# Show message with timer

Tags: c#

I have an application with 2 form,

1 form reading from .csv file to insert to SQL Server,

1 form will be show when trouble happen ( Can not reading .csv file or reading error)

My code as below:

```
public void Timer_tick ( object sender eventargs e)
{
   PushData();  // with time interval =100    
}

public void PushData()
{
   Form2 fr = new Form2();

   // function to reading .csv file
   if ( checkData(name) == "OK") 
   {
     //update data to SQL Server    
   }
   else 
   {
      timer1.Stop();
      fr.Show();  // User need to click OK button to hide Form2 and come back Form1
      this.Refresh();
   }
}
```

It's only one time show Form2.

But after User click button at Form2 to comback Form1.  But Form1 not working normal with timer.

Please help me to solve this application.

Thank you!

Comment: Having trouble understanding, but is the problem that you don't restart the timer after Form2 closes?

Comment: Yes, i want to restart the timer after Form2 closed.

Answer (score 0):

Show the form as dialog, and then restart the timer when finished:

```
timer1.Stop();

fr.ShowDialog();  // User need to click OK button to hide Form2 and come back Form1

timer1.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the message box rather than using form2 and display error message. Refer the similar and sample code below.

```
{
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PushData();
        }

        public void PushData()
        {
            Form2 fr = new Form2();
            // function to reading .csv file
            if (checkBox1.Checked==true)
            {
                progressBar1.Value += 1;
                //update data to SQL Server

            }

            else
            {

                timer1.Stop();

                MessageBox.Show("Error message");

                timer1.Start();

            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: My application need to use an other form. Because need to show other form, after that user type the password and click button OK then Form2 closed. And timer restart with Form1

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and let me know is it working or not

```
public void Timer_tick ( object sender eventargs e)
{
    PushData();  // with time interval =100    
}

public void PushData()
{
   Form2 fr = new Form2();
   frm.Closed += fr_Closed;
   // function to reading .csv file
   if ( checkData(name) == "OK") 
   {
     //update data to SQL Server    
   }
   else 
   {
      timer1.Stop();
      fr.Show();  // User need to click OK button to hide Form2 and come back Form1
      this.Refresh();
   }
}

void fr_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     timer1.Start();
}
```